# Same game in OGL ESv2 doesnt work with OGL3

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, opengl-3

I've coded a engine which is able of drawing with OpenGL ESv2 or OpenGL 3 Core Profile API.
But recently the OpenGL 3 part got broken and I can't remember what I changed nor can I look in the svn commitlog, cause I did host it at bountysource which is down now and I carried it over to Google (but with broken OGL3 port).

With OpenGL ESv2 everything works fine, but with OpenGL 3 everything is stretched and mirrored horizontally. Both even use the same matrices and vertices.

Do not be confused. The OpenGL ESv2 and OpenGL 3 renderers use different ways to render it.

OpenGL ESv2 uses VBO.
OpenGL 3 uses VAO and VBO.

My engine is open source, so, you can look into it here: [Source Code](http://code.google.com/p/photonlibrary/source/browse/#svn/trunk).

These should be the important parts: [Sprite Class](http://code.google.com/p/photonlibrary/source/browse/trunk/src/Photon/Graphics/Sprite.cpp), [Base Window Class](http://code.google.com/p/photonlibrary/source/browse/trunk/src/Photon/Window/WindowBase.cpp), [GL3 Window Class](http://code.google.com/p/photonlibrary/source/browse/trunk/src/Photon/Window/WindowWinGL3.cpp), [GL ESv2 Window Class](http://code.google.com/p/photonlibrary/source/browse/trunk/src/Photon/Window/WindowWinGLES.cpp)

Shaders:

GLv2: [frag](http://code.google.com/p/photonlibrary/source/browse/trunk/src/Photon/Graphics/esshader.frag), [vert](http://code.google.com/p/photonlibrary/source/browse/trunk/src/Photon/Graphics/esshader.vert)

GL3: [frag](http://code.google.com/p/photonlibrary/source/browse/trunk/src/Photon/Graphics/shader.frag), [vert](http://code.google.com/p/photonlibrary/source/browse/trunk/src/Photon/Graphics/shader.vert)

Here are some example pictures:
[image: OpenGL 3 - Menu]
[image: OpenGL 3 - Ingame]
[image: OpenGL ESv2 - Menu]
[image: OpenGL ESv2 - Ingame]

I would be really, really glad and thankful if someone would deliver me the solution to this problem and maybe I would give a small reward for it.

edit:
with a 480x800 window, gldebugger shows this matrix:
modviewmat
{1, -0, 0, 0}
{0, 1, 0, 0}
{0, 0, 1, 0}
{5, 770, 0, 1}

projmat
{2, 0, 0, 0}
{0, 2, 0, 0}
{0, 0, -1, 0}
{-1, -1, -0, 1}

Comment: You're having problems with aspect ratio. This is governed by two things: the viewport and the perspective matrix. You never gave us the code you use to compute the perspective matrix. Also, if you could make the images not be gigantic, that'd be great.

Comment: For future reference Alt+PrintScreen will capture only the topmost/active window.  Should save you some cropping work :)

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/photonlibrary/source/browse/trunk/src/Photon/Graphics/Camera.cpp and http://code.google.com/p/photonlibrary/source/browse/trunk/src/Photon/Math/Matrix3f.cpp.. The matrices are the same for gles and gl3. so, i didnt thought it would be relevant

Comment: gldebugger says this if it helps you (480x800): modviewmat
{1, -0, 0, 0}
{0, 1, 0, 0}
{0, 0, 1, 0}
{5, 770, 0, 1}

projmat
{2, 0, 0, 0}
{0, 2, 0, 0}
{0, 0, -1, 0}
{-1, -1, -0, 1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so dumb..it was cause I have 2 class.
1 base class and 1 plattform specific implementation which derived from the base class.
All variables were created in the base class AND in the other.

So, I had handles for the matrices in the base class and in the other class.
The OpenGL handles were initialized in the base class. In the gl3 class there are handles too but they arent initialized, since its the job of the base class.

tl;dr pseudocode:

base class: glhandle projmatrix
gl3class:   glhandle projmatrix

baseclass::init(): (baseclass).promatrix.init
gl3class::update(): (gl3class).projmatrix.update

:/

Comment: You can accept your own answer (you won't recieve reputation of course) to mark it solved. Also it is again a example why OOP makes things harder instead of simpler.